# Getting exception information from QuickBooks Online

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, quickbooks-online

Is there a way to get more specific information about the exception/error that occurred when interacting with QuickBooks Online?

I've been messing around and testing certain things and I would get an exception but all it would say is "BadRequest" from a IdsException, which isn't too helpful. So I was just curious if there was a way to extract more information. I know they put more information and such in the response body but since I'm using a DataService object I'm not sure how to see the response body.

I've checked Intuits documentation and checked all the properties and methods I could think to check but haven't had any luck so far.

If I need to put up an example of what I'm doing I can. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using an SDK?  Please post the request/response.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the .NET SDK from Intuit. And that's the thing, there is none that I know of how to get because all I have to do with the DataService object is define the object (`Dim act As New Account()` then fill in some fields) and then calling something like `dataService.Add(act)`. So the request and response are handled already, I just don't know how to view the response information other than when something like the `Add(...)` method returns the object information back.

Comment: Please enable request/response logging : https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/logging#Request_and_Response_Log
From there, you can check the request against the documentation to make sure you are passing the correct fields/format, and use the API Explorer to execute the request directly.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. That sounds like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending information to QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks does not like what you are sending you will get a `ValidationException`.

This exception is clearly not too helpful as it is very vague. However, if you catch it and then look for the `InnerExceptions` array of `IdsError` you can find more information about what actually went wrong.

In my situation I would catch the main exception, `ex`, and have to do this:

`ex.InnerException.InnerExceptions(i).Message`

From there you can either display it or concat all the errors together or anything else you want.